# Get Clicked View and position from nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to display meesages in recyclerview.

Message 1
     attachment-1
     attachment-2

Message-2

attachement-1

Messge-3(without attachemnts)

I'm creating a new Recyclerview if row has an attachments.The **click listener isn't working for the RecyclerView** the listener works fine for all other view elements except RecyclerView.

**MsgCursorAdapter**

```
public class MsgCursorAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1=1;
private static final int VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2=2;     
private Context mcontext;
private Cursor mCursor;
private static PostMessageClickListener itemClickListener;
public MsgCursorAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor,PostMessageClickListener listener){
        super(context,cursor);
        mcontext=context;
        mCursor=cursor;
        itemClickListener=listener;
    }

  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position))
            {
                PostItem postItem=PostItem.fromCursor(mCursor);
                if (postItem.isFromMe())
                {
                    return VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1;
        }
        else{
            return VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2;
        }
        }
     }


   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
        PostItem postitem = PostItem.fromCursor(cursor);
 switch (getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition())) {
            case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1:
                ViewHolder_Type1 viewholder1 = (ViewHolder_Type1) holder;
                TextView mytimeView = (TextView) viewholder1.mytimeTextView;
                mytimeView.setText(postitem.getPostTime());
                TextView mymsgView = (TextView) viewholder1.mymessageTextView;
                mymsgView.setText(postitem.getPostMsg());
                RecyclerView mRecyclerview1=(RecyclerView) viewholder1.attachments_list;
                if (attachmentArrayList.size()>0)
                {
                    mRecyclerview1.setHasFixedSize(true);
                   PostAttachmentAdapter mAdapter= new PostAttachmentAdapter(attachmentArrayList,mcontext,postitem.getPostColumnid());
                    mRecyclerview1.setAdapter(mAdapter);//);
                    mRecyclerview1.setLayoutManager(new CustomLinearLayoutManager(mcontext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                    mRecyclerview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {mRecyclerview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
                break;

            case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2:
                ViewHolder_Type2 viewholder2 = (ViewHolder_Type2) holder;
                TextView timeView = (TextView) viewholder2.timeTextView;
                timeView.setText(postitem.getPostTime());
                TextView msgView = (TextView) viewholder2.messageTextView;
                msgView.setText(postitem.getPostMsg());
                RecyclerView mRecyclerview2=(RecyclerView) viewholder2.attachments_list;
                if (attachmentArrayList.size()>0)
                {
                    mRecyclerview2.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    PostAttachmentAdapter mAdapter= new PostAttachmentAdapter(attachmentArrayList,mcontext,postitem.getPostColumnid());
                    mRecyclerview2.setAdapter(mAdapter);//);
                    mRecyclerview2.setLayoutManager(new CustomLinearLayoutManager(mcontext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                    mRecyclerview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    mRecyclerview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;

        default:
        break;
          }
         }
    }

 @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;

        switch (viewType) {

            case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_1:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.mypost, parent, false);
                ViewHolder_Type1 vh1 = new ViewHolder_Type1(v);
                return vh1;

            case VIEW_HOLDER_TYPE_2:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false);
                ViewHolder_Type2 vh2 = new ViewHolder_Type2(v);
                return vh2;
            default:
        break;
          }

    return null;

    }

 public static class ViewHolder_Type1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView mymessageTextView, mytimeTextView;
        public RecyclerView attachments_list;
        public ViewHolder_Type1(View v) {
            super(v);
            mymessageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mymessageTextView);
            mytimeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mytimeTextView);
            attachments_list=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_attachment_recyclerview);
            mymessageTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
            attachments_list.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemClickListener.itemClicked(v,getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }


  public static class ViewHolder_Type2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView messageTextView, timeTextView;
        public RecyclerView attachments_list;
        public ViewHolder_Type2(View v) {
            super(v);
            messageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
            timeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
            attachments_list=(RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.post_attachment_recyclerview);
            messageTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
            attachments_list.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.itemClicked(v,getLayoutPosition());
        }
    }

  public interface PostMessageClickListener
    {
        public void itemClicked(View v, int position);

    }
```

**PostAttachmentAdapter**

public class PostAttachmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<PostAttachment> mAttachmentsArray;
private String postCloumnid;
public PostAttachmentAdapter(ArrayList<PostAttachment> attachmentsArray,Context context,String postColumnId)
{
    this.mContext=context;
    this.mAttachmentsArray=attachmentsArray;
    this.postCloumnid=postColumnId;

}

@Override
public PostAttachmentAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.post_attachment_image,null);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    File f = new File(mAttachmentsArray.get(position).getFileName());
    String filename = "Thumb_"+f.getName();
    if (FileUtility.getMimeType(filename).startsWith("image/")) {
        String targetPath= Util.getAttachmentPathForUser(Integer.toString(CurrentUser.getInstance().getId()),postCloumnid, filename);

        File thumb=new File(targetPath);
        if (thumb.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(targetPath);
            myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap,250,250,true);
            myBitmap= ImageUtility.fastblur(myBitmap,0.4f,7);
            holder.imgViewIcon.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
        else {
            holder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_photo_black_48dp);
        }
    }
    else {
        holder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_insert_drive_file_black_48dp);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mAttachmentsArray.size();
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    public ImageView imgViewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.post_attachment);
    }

}
```

How can I create Click listener for the nested RecyclerView Items

I've tried searching SO for similar solution I didn't find any

Comment: This has been viewed too many times. Do you already have an answer?